# Map phonetic string to possible alternate strings to match against dynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

We're integrating Amazon's Alexa to work with our application. We have created a dictionary of items that Alexa might be asked, in DynamoDB. Now we need an algorithm to match the text from Alexa to the strings stored in the DynamoDB table which would be phonetically similar, but possibly differently spelled or with special characters in between, e.g.

> "X-Men" may be requested as "xmen" or "ex men" or "x men"
>
> "Claire" may be requested as "clare" or "clair"

I find the [Amazon DynamoDB-ElasticSearch Integration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-logstash-plugin-search-dynamodb-content-using-elasticsearch/) a plausible option, but i haven't learnt enough about it yet. This could be pretty expensive too.

I also tried to find out if there are node modules that would help find similar strings that I could match against the database.

The [fuzzy search node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzy) would probably not work for us either especially because we have the constraint of finding a single match and not a list of possible match for a single string input.

Eg. A search for `"Xmen"` should return only `"X-Men"` and not `"X-Men"` and `"Ex-servicemen"`

My last resort would be to write an **Approximate String Matching Algorithm** along with **Levenshtein distance computing algorithm** from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

According to [DynamoDB Query API Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) :

> **Query :**
>
> A Query operation uses the primary key of a table or a secondary index
>   to directly access items from that table or index.
>
> Use the **KeyConditionExpression** parameter to provide a specific value
>   for the partition key. The Query operation will return all of the
>   items from the table or index with that partition key value. You can
>   optionally narrow the scope of the Query operation by specifying a
>   **sort key** value and a comparison operator in KeyConditionExpression.
>   **You can use the ScanIndexForward parameter to get results in forward
>   or reverse order, by sort key.**
>
> **KeyConditionExpression** :
>
> The condition that specifies the key value(s) for items to be
>   retrieved by the Query action.
>
> The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key
>   value. The condition can also perform one of several comparison tests
>   on a single sort key value. Query can use KeyConditionExpression to
>   retrieve one item with a given partition key value and sort key value,
>   or several items that have the same partition key value but different
>   sort key values.
>
> The partition key equality test is required, and must be specified in
>   the following format:
>
> `partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval`
>
> If you also want to provide a condition for the sort key, it must be
>   combined using AND with the condition for the sort key. Following is
>   an example, using the = comparison operator for the sort key:
>
> `partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval AND sortKeyName = :sortkeyval`
>
> Valid comparisons for the sort key condition are as follows:
>
> - `sortKeyName = :sortkeyval` - true if the sort key value is equal to :sortkeyval.
> - `sortKeyName < :sortkeyval` - true if the sort key value is less than :sortkeyval.
> - `sortKeyName <= :sortkeyval` - true if the sort key value is less than or equal to :sortkeyval.
> - `sortKeyName > :sortkeyval` - true if the sort key value is greater than :sortkeyval.
> - `sortKeyName >= :sortkeyval` - true if the sort key value is greater than or equal to :sortkeyval.
> - `sortKeyName BETWEEN :sortkeyval1 AND :sortkeyval2` - true if the sort key value is greater than or equal to :sortkeyval1, and less than
>     or equal to :sortkeyval2.
> - `begins_with ( sortKeyName, :sortkeyval )` - true if the sort key value begins with a particular operand. (You cannot use this function
>     with a sort key that is of type Number.)
>
> You can optionally use the ExpressionAttributeNames parameter to
>   replace the names of the partition key and sort key with placeholder
>   tokens. This option might be necessary if an attribute name conflicts
>   with a DynamoDB reserved word. For example, the following
>   KeyConditionExpression parameter causes an error because Size is a
>   reserved word:
>
> ```
> Size = :myval
> ```
>
> To work around this, define a placeholder (such a #S) to represent the
>   attribute name Size. KeyConditionExpression then is as follows:
>
> ```
> #S = :myval
> ```
>
> For a list of reserved words, see Reserved Words in the Amazon
>   DynamoDB Developer Guide.
>
> For more information on ExpressionAttributeNames and
>   ExpressionAttributeValues, see Using Placeholders for Attribute Names
>   and Values in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide.
>
> Type: String
>
> Required: No

**Your Scenario Can be converted to following Code :**

```
$tableName = "genericTable";
$response = $dynamodb->query([
    'TableName' => $tableName,
    'IndexName' => 'OrderCreationDateIndex',
    'KeyConditionExpression' => 'partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval AND sortKeyName = :sortkeyval',
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  [
        ':partitionkeyval' => ['S' => 'pkey'],
        ':sortkeyval' => ['S' => 'sortkey']
    ],
    'Select' => 'ALL_PROJECTED_ATTRIBUTES',
    'ScanIndexForward' => false,
    'ConsistentRead' => true,
    'Limit' => 5,
    'ReturnConsumedCapacity' => 'TOTAL'
]);
```